How to prove that $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ is a simple Lie algebra? Relationship with the complexification to $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$?
I know that there's counterexample which a simple lie algebra whose complexification is not simple, see here.
However, I'm not sure if a simple complex lie algebra's real form is still simple or not.
If not, what's the classical way to show $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ is simple?

Complexification takes ideals to ideals, so if a real Lie algebra is not simple then its complexification is not simple. Taking the contrapositive, if the complexification is simple, the original real Lie algebra is simple.

If I don’t understand wrongly, if a real Lie algebra  is not simple, it can be decomposed into direct sum of simple ideals, so is it true that the complexification takes simple ideals to simple ideals?

@KennyS: You don't even need a decomposition into simple ideals (for which you would need to invoke the corresponding statement with "semisimple"). You just use that if the real form has any ideal besides $0$ and itself, then so does its complexificstion.

Thank you for your comment! I understand.
